# Put router configuration in a separate file in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am trying to take out router configuration from `app.js` file and put it in a separate file (`app.router.js`). This is probably an easy thing to do but I don't know how to do it.

Current `app.js` file looks like this:

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {

  static inject() { return [Router]; };

  constructor(router) {

    this.router = router;

    // router - put this part in a separate file
    this.router.configure(config => {

      config.title = 'demo';
      config.options.pushState = true;
      config.map([

        // home routes
        { route: ['','home'], moduleId: './home/home', nav: true, title:'Home' },

        // User routes
        { route: ['user/register'], moduleId: './user/register', nav: true, title:'User Registration'}

      ]);

    });

  }
}
```

Once the configuration part is in a separate file, I believe I have call it like this in `app.js`:

```
this.router.configure(myRouterConfig);
```

Please let me know how to do it with code example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is easier to understand when you realize that the argument you pass to `this.router.configure` is just a function. To put your router configuration in a separate file, just have that file export a function that takes one argument (`config`).

```
// app.router.js
export default function (config) {
  config.title = 'demo';
  config.options.pushState = true;

  config.map([
    // home routes
    { route: ['','home'], moduleId: './home/home', nav: true, title:'Home' },
    // User routes
    { route: ['user/register'], moduleId: './user/register', nav: true, title:'User Registration'}
  ]);      
}
```

Then, in `app.js`:

```
import appRouter from 'app.router';

// ...then...
this.router.configure(appRouter);
```

You can, of course, name `appRouter` anything you want.

Comment: Thank you, Jordan! That was exactly what I needed!